# Python dataframe: how to remove first column (row number)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have manually constructed the dataframe (df1,code below).
For this dataframe df1, how could I remove the first column (row number)?
Many thanks in advance

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['2021-3-22', '2021-4-7', '2021-4-18', '2021-5-12'],
"x": [3, 3, 3, 0 ]})

Output:
date    x
0   2021-3-22   3
1   2021-4-7    3
2   2021-4-18   3
3   2021-5-12   0
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the first row or column. They are different things.

Comment: may I ask what you did for research? You faster find an answer googling that than writing the question down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `set_index` method.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"date": ['2021-3-22', '2021-4-7', '2021-4-18', '2021-5-12'],
"x": [3, 3, 3, 0 ]})

df1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The default dataframe representation will display index numbers by default. If you want to see your dataframe without index you could use [`.to_string` method with `index=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html#pandas-dataframe-to-string).

```
>>> df1
        date  x
0  2021-3-22  3
1   2021-4-7  3
2  2021-4-18  3
3  2021-5-12  0
>>> 
>>> print(df1.to_string(index=False))
     date  x
2021-3-22  3
 2021-4-7  3
2021-4-18  3
2021-5-12  0
```